# I need help fixing an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, html

Hi, I was wondering why my while loop isn't working and why it is going into an infinite loop (if that's the correct term).
I'm really new to coding so please make the answer as simple as possible, thanks :)

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Oppgave 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Oppgave 1</h1>
    <h2>Alle tall mellom 1 - 1000 som er delelige<br>
    med 3 bortsett fra 27, 33, 300, 450</h2>

    <p id="AlleTall"></p>

    <script>
        var strOutput = document.getElementById("AlleTall");
        var i=0;

        while(i<=1000){
            if(i===0) || i===27 || i===33 || i===450)
                strOutput.innterHTML+=("");
            } else {
                strOutput.innterHTML+=(i + ", ");
                i=i+3;
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here's also a screenshot of the code :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33MSW.png)

Comment: Put the code in the question, not an image of the code. It is not possible for use to copy and paste text from an image.

Comment: you forgot to increase your counter in one of the branches

Comment: You are conditionally incrementing `i`... I.e. if i is `0` it will never be incremented.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: Hi, I'm happy to see a fellow Brackets user :D. Would you mind replacing the image with actual code (see [how do I format my blocks of code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)) ?

Comment: It can help a lot if you quickly learn how to debug program code. You can start [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C.M is correct, in one of the sections of code you do not increase the index if it is true meaning it will be true forever because it will always be stuck on that number and therefore never gets to the other part.

Comment: Depending on how new you are if you need help locating this feel free to ask. Also feel free to ask me to clarify any other terminology.